# Read GraphQL mutation result while using event sourcing

Tags: python, graphql, event-sourcing

In recent project we are trying to adopt an `event sourcing` pattern. For backend API we decided to use GraphQL. As far as I understand changing data in this type of architecture should be asynchronous. On the other hand, GraphQL mutations usually return modified data. How to connect those two words?

To be more precise, let's consider user register mutation. How, for example, FE can tell the user that the selected user name is taken?

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://techblog.commercetools.com/modeling-graphql-mutations-52d4369f73b1) on mutation design and event sourcing. The GraphQL API gateway submits events and waits for the result before submitting its result to the frontend.

Comment: Thanks, that definately an useful article. What I miss there is an example implementation.

Comment: The company uses the Scala implementation and I have built something in JS. I think you are probably not struggling with the GraphQL part but rather everything else. IMO ES is one of the most complicated architectures at scale.

Comment: What if waiting is not acceptable? You never know how long it can take.